# Access to a link and get data from it with Ionic

Tags: php, html, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am currently using **Ionic** to create a mobile application. To resume, the users can scan a barcode and get details about the parcel.

To do this, the application needs to contact the server with a specific link like :

> `https://mywebsite.com/parcels/getinformations/{id_parcel}`

Then, the server will return an array *(?)* with information, and the application will display them on the screen.

But I don't know how to make a function call a specific link and get data from it in Ionic *(and in general)*. I also use Laravel for my website *(I don't know if it is more specific with Laravel or not)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in yout app.module you need import HttpModule like this:

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

and then on imports array:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,

  ],
```

now in your component you can use a conexion whit your server like this:

1 - import http:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

2 - declare on constructo:

```
constructor( public http: Http, ){}
```

3- use:

```
 let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    let items = { "var1" : 'send1', "var2" : 'send2'};
    this.http.post('https//:yourUrl.com/api', items, options).subscribe(data => {

      console.log(data);
     },
     err => {
      console.log(err);

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Http get or post depend on your own way

See this

https://www.djamware.com/post/59924f9080aca768e4d2b12e/ionic-3-consuming-rest-api-using-new-angular-43-httpclient